# replaceWith jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to replace a div's content to reset the construction of a slimbox2 gallery.

however as there are / in the image src it takes it as a javascript error.
I remember there was some character you had to replace with or am i wrong?

```
function destroyGallery(){
    $('#imageGal').replaceWith("<li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/1.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" id="mainProdPicture"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/2.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/3.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li>");

}
```

Comment: An `<li>` element should have a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotation, change it to:

```
function destroyGallery(){
    $('#imageGal').replaceWith('<li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/1.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" id="mainProdPicture"/></li>\
        <li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/2.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li>\
        <li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/3.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li>');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double quote conflict.

Try :

```
function destroyGallery(){
    $('#imageGal').replaceWith('<li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/1.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" id="mainProdPicture"/></li><li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/2.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li><li><img src="images/products/castles/camelot/medium/3.jpg" title="Camelot Castle" /></li>');   
}
```

Comment: I don't think line breaks are accepted in the middle of string as well, but yeah, quotes are the main problem.